# Joining Models And Passing To Template

Tags: django, django-models

I have multiple related `models` and on a single page I need to access data from different `models` on a variety of conditions. Most of this data is accessed without a `form` as only a few fields need to be manipulated by the user.

To give you an idea of how interconnected my Models are:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first = models.ManyToManyField(First)
    second= models.ManyToManyField(Second)

class First(models.Model):
    [...]

class Second(models.Model):
    first = models.ManyToManyField(First)

class Third(models.Model):
    first = models.ForeignKey(First)

class Fourth(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    second = models.ForeignKey(Second)
    third = models.ForeignKey(Third)

class Fifth(models.Model):
    fourth = models.ForeignKey(Fourth)

class Sixth(models.Model):
    fifth = models.ForeignKey(Fifth)
```

I'm having a lot of difficulty passing this data to my `template` and displaying it in efficiently. I originally displayed it to the user in a horrendous way as I just wanted to see if my data was accessible/displaying properly. This is an example of some of the dodgy code I used to test that my data was being passed properly:

```
{% for second in user.second.all %}
{% for first in second.first.all %}
[...]
{% for fourth in user.fourth.all %}
[...]
{% if fourth.first_id == first.id  and fourth.second_id == second.id %}
{% if fourth.checked == True %}
[...]
{% else %}
[...]
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
[...]
```

Isn't it an abomination, and it goes deeper. Now I am trying to reformat this. I know that my processing should be done within my view rather than my template. The thing is I can't just filter out a lot of the data in my `views` as I need a lot of it in the `template` at different times (eg I might have 20 pieces of data in a `model` and I need to access all 20, but some when the `id` match, some when the `id` and `type` match etc. It's a lot of template side logic - I think that's bad).

This is the kind of thing I have been trying to do so far but am having no luck:

```
second = Second.objects.filter(user__id=user.id) .select_related('First')
```

Any help with how to join/pass all these `model`s to my `view` and access the data without the nested nested loops, or even just pointers on how to approach this would be appreciated. I's also unsure if I should be aiming to join as many `model`s as possible then pass into my `view` or pass many separate `models`.

Thank you.

Comment: You could pass it as a differently named `context` in the view but this would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

you are serializer the data use a [drf serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) you will need to use a nested serializer

example for nested serializer

```py
    class HospitalsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Hospitals
            fields = '__all__'
    
    class HealthProductSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        hospital_list = HospitalsSerializer(many=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = HealthProduct
            exclude = ("created_at", "updated_at")
```